# How to count the number of rows resulting from a query with left join and max operation?

Tags: mysql, database

To begin with, I have this table of posts. Each post can have 0 or more tags. Tags have their own read permissions (numerical).

To illustrate, I have 3 tables: Posts, TagRel and Tags.

```
Posts: post_id, post_title, post_body
Tags: tag_id, tag_name, tag_perm
TagRel: post_id, tag_id

-----------------------------------------------------
post_id   |    post_title     |     post_body
-----------------------------------------------------
0         | Sample Title      | Sample Body
1         | Sample Title 1    | Sample Body
2         | Sample Title 2    | Sample Body
-----------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------
tag_id   |    tag_name     |     tag_perm
-----------------------------------------------------
1        | Top Secret      | 90
2        | General         | 0
-----------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------
tag_id   |   post_id
-----------------------------------------------------
1        |    1
-----------------------------------------------------
```

What I need to do is count posts that have tag_perm <= N. This should also include posts that don't have tags, because it means that those posts are OK to read.

Let's say that N is 0, we need to count posts that have both no tags, and with tags having <= 0 tag_perm. From our illustration, it should return 2.

This is my query for selecting that 2 posts:

```
SELECT p.*,
(CASE WHEN MAX(t.tag_perm) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE MAX(t.tag_perm) END) as read_perm 
FROM tbl_posts p 
LEFT JOIN tbl_tagrel r ON r.post_id = p.post_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_tags t ON t.tag_id = r.tag_id 
GROUP BY p.post_id 
HAVING read_perm <= N
```

I'm having problem getting the count, this is what I've got and it still don't yield the desired results.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.post_id) 
FROM tbl_posts p 
LEFT JOIN tbl_tagrel r ON r.post_id = p.post_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_tags t ON t.tag_id = r.tag_id
```

Comment: does your first query return the two desired rows?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

Since your first query returns the correct number of rows, use it as a subquery and count it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT p.post_id,
        (CASE WHEN MAX(t.tag_perm) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE MAX(t.tag_perm) END) as read_perm, 
    FROM tbl_posts p 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_tagrel r ON r.post_id = p.post_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_tags t ON t.tag_id = r.tag_id 
    GROUP BY p.post_id 
    HAVING read_perm <= N
    ) sub
```

Comment: thanks for the input! performance wise, will might this be slower than attempting to do a single query for counting those rows?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it in a single query, because of the aggregation.